# How to Copy Values from worksheet and Paste them in One with Refrencing to Sheets name

Tags: vba, excel

Can you please help me to write a VBA code to retrieve some data as:

I have an Excel sheet which contains some Worksheets. Some of these sheets called like:

- region_1
- region_2
- region_3
- region_4
- region_5
- region_6

All of these sheets have same Header so what I think to do is:

1. Create a Temporary Sheet called "Temp"
2. Insert a Column called "Areas" which will track next added Worksheet's Name
3. Copy Header and values from Sheet(region_1) and Paste them to "Temp"
4. Copy Values from region_2,region_3,region_4,region_5,region_6 and Paste them to "Temp"
5. Finally Copy Temp as New Workbook in a folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Any sample code and/or data is best provided in advance so we understand what you're trying to do. ;)

Comment: Recording a Macro I have a big idea on how to select them and copy paste to new sheet the only part which is confusing for me is the part that track the name for cells from one sheet and save it to related column. I am totally lost here!

Comment: you mean to  Copy a chart from one sheet to another using the target sheet data for the chart in Excel ?

Comment: Chart? what is chart? No I jst want to copy all sheets in one sheet but I need to know where data come from?

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
Sub CopySheets()
Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Dim rNew As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, wbo As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Set wbo = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsNew = wbNew.Worksheets(1)
    rNew = 1
    For Each ws In wbo.Worksheets
        With ws
            If Left(ws.Name, 6) = "region" Then
                r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If rNew = 1 Then ' copy headers
                    wsNew.Range(wsNew.Cells(1, 1), wsNew.Cells(r, c)).Value = _
                        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(r, c)).Value
                    rNew = r + 1
                Else ' don't copy headers
                    wsNew.Range(wsNew.Cells(rNew, 1), wsNew.Cells(r + rNew - 2, c)).Value = _
                        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(r, c)).Value
                    rNew = r + rNew - 1
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Call wbNew.Save("N:\wb.xls")
End Sub
```

Worked for me. With this solution you don't have to use a temp sheet. It will copy all worksheets, that begin with "region".

Comment: Hi MiVoth, thanks and sorry for late reply. Honestly I think this is not what exactly I was looking for. According to your code and what I understand, you are trying to grab data from sheets which has "region" but what if I have 20 sheets starting with region? I mean is there any way to select data based on the name but more specifically?